# Click one div and make another click to another div

Tags: jquery

I want to make that when one div is clicked, it makes the same effect like if another div was clicked.

I mean, when .whole-link is clicked, I want that to make like if 'nav.laynav.primary li span' had been clicked.

is there any option?
I have something like this:

```js
jQuery('.id-25 .row .col.black-white .element-wrap:nth-child(4) .whole-link').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('nav.laynav.primary li.menu-item-type-post_type:nth-child(3) ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(4)').trigger("click");
    });
    jQuery('nav.laynav.primary li.menu-item-type-post_type:nth-child(3) ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(4)').on("click", function(){
        console.log('hello');
    })
```

Comment: Code shown looks valid , so long as the whole-link exists at the time it is run. If it's not working you need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a click on the span element like this:

```js
$('.whole-link').on("click", function() {
  $("nav.laynav.primary li span").trigger("click");
});
$("nav.laynav.primary li span").on("click", function() {
  console.log("nav.laynav.primary li span clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whole-link">
  whole link
</div>
<nav class="laynav primary">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Example</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: yeah the console.log runs but nothing happens.I edited my code.

Comment: @Vander Could you also share your HTML in your question?

Comment: here it is: https://gyazo.com/dae0cae69c67772beb0225df79985eae (the first link i click) and the second one: https://gyazo.com/1a22111c18535bc96837a3c734a24d68
The thing is that this anchors doesnt go where they should to unless you are on the same page (where the id is). And it works everywhere, this is the only anchor that doesnt work :S No other id has the same name